# Connection via Java results in com.sforce.soap.apex-error

Tags: apex, webservices, java

I am a little bit confused. I am a long term SF-developer who is now making his first steps with Java. I just wanted to make a connectiontest with this page:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_java_sample.htm

Unfortunately I can't use the code because when I try this line:

import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

I get the message: "package com.sforce.ws does not exist". The other imports are all ok. As I am not experienced with Java, my tests were quite limited. Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance, this site here is the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import sfdc-wsc from either [github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc) or from [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc). Your exact steps may vary depending on your IDE, but generally speaking, you need to add this library to your class path. In Eclipse, go to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARs, then add the sfdc-wsc JAR to this list. The package com.sforce.ws will be available in your project's browser and you can autocomplete code from that package. Other IDEs will follow a similar mechanism, so you may need to adjust make files, other dialog boxes, etc if you're not using Eclipse. Also, read [Step 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_quickstart_import_WSDLs.htm) for how to use WSC. If you skip this step, expect problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I did all of this. I created a partner.jar with the sfdc-wsc and imported it into Eclipse (and even tested it with Netbeans). I can import things like "import com.sforce.soap.partner.*;" without any problems, just the .ws- imports are not working. Would it be helpful, if I share my java library with you guys?
Edit: Here is the Link to the library in my Googledrive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3x4QsTbfgooVVVKU1VaRWdYY2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh damnit, I am too stupid for this here -.-

Thanks for your help, just read again what you have writte and I missed to import the sfdc-wsc.jar file aswell. After that, all the .ws-imports are working. Thanks and sorry for the stupid questions -.-

Comment: @Dhektar It's okay, we all make mistakes from time to time. I'm glad you were able to get your imports working.